# Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be a function. Let $S$ and $T$ be subsets of $A$. Prove that if f is injective, then $f(S − T) = f(S) − f(T)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So I started my proof with let  $x \in f(S-T)$ and so by definition there exist a $s \in S-T  $ such that $f(s) = x$. Then I said that $s \in S$ and $s \notin T$. Then because $S$ is subset of $A$, $s \in A$. But I am confused as to where to go after this or what to do after this t get what I want.

Comment: How have you tried to use the fact that f is injective?

Comment: I have not because I do not know how to get to that point with what I have

Comment: Backing up a little bit, we just figuredout $f(s)=x$ and that $s\in S,s\notin T$.  Can we say something about whether or not we have $f(s)\in f(S), f(s)\in f(T)$ and/or $f(s)\in(f(S)-f(T))$?  Which of those are $f(s)$ in and which of those are $f(s)$ not in.  Why?

Comment: well if s is not an element of T then f(s) is in f(S-T) and f(S)

Comment: You are correct that $f(s)\in f(S)$ as well as $f(S-T)$, that follows from definition.  What about $f(T)$?  Is it in or is it not in that (*or do we not know*)?  Be sure to explain why.  This is the important one to figure out.

Comment: no right because s is not an element of T so f(s) is not an element of f(T)?

Comment: That is the incorrect reasoning.  Take a constant function $g~:~\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ where $g(x)=1$ for all $x$.  Then despite $-1\not\in [0,\infty)$ you still have $1=g(-1)\in g([0,\infty))=\{1\}$.  We know something special about $f$ though that will help us here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=f(S)$ and $W=f(T)$ be subsets of $B$.
If $f$ is one-to-one function, then there exist a the inverse function of $f$ such that $f^{-1}: B \rightarrow A$.

The set mapped for $f^{-1}(H-W)$ is exactly $S-T$, so

$$S-T=f^{-1}(H-W)$$
Applying $f$ at both sides, 
\begin{align}
f(S-T)&=H-W \\ &= f(S)-f(T)
\end{align}